# Diophantine equation with binomial coefficient

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Suppose that $p$ is a prime number and $p \le q \le p^2$ is an
>   integer. How many solutions are there to the following equation?
>
> $$\binom{p^2}{q}-\binom{q}{p}=1$$

This question was proposed for Romanian national olympiad in 2006. There is a very long [solution](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h484036p2717400) in the AOPS website for the problem. I was wondering if there is a simpler solution!